# LeetCode 14. longest common prefix

Tags: java

Question:

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string among an array of strings. If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

Example 1:

Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]
  Output: "fl"

Example 2:

Input: ["dog","racecar","car"]
  Output: ""

Explanation: There is no common prefix among the input strings.

Code:

```java
public class Solution {
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
        if(strs==null || strs.length==0)
            return "";
        for(int i=0;i<strs[0].length();i++) {
            char x = strs[0].charAt(i);
            for(int j=0;j<strs.length;j++) {
                if((strs[j].length()==i)||(strs[j].charAt(i)!=x)) {
                    return strs[0].substring(0,i);
                }
            }
        }
        return strs[0];
    }
}
```

This is the second solution, but I don't understand the inner loop.
I think if the second element in strs returns a string and ends the for loop, the third element will not have a chance to be compared.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check same position in all of the words and just compare it.

```
         positions
word    0 1 2 3 4 5
=====================
w[0]    F L O W E R
w[1]    F L O W
w[2]    F L I G H T
```

In Java:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = {"dog","racecar","car"};

        String prefix = commonPrefix(words);

        System.out.println(prefix);
        // return empty string

        String[] words2 = {"dog","racecar","car"};

        String prefix2 = commonPrefix(words2);

        System.out.println(prefix2);
        // Return "fl" (2 letters)
    }

    private static String commonPrefix(String[] words) {
        // Common letter counter
        int counter = 0;

        external:
        for (int i = 0; i < words[0].length(); i++) {

            // Get letter from first word
            char letter = words[0].charAt(i);

            // Check rest of the words on that same positions
            for (int j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
                // Break when word is shorter or letter is different
                if (words[j].length() <= i || letter != words[j].charAt(i)) {
                    break external;
                }
            }

            // Increase counter, because all of words
            // has the same letter (e.g. "E") on the same position (e.g. position "5")
            counter++;
        }

        // Return proper substring
        return words[0].substring(0, counter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop is itterating over all chars in the first string of array. Second loop is checking char at `i` posistion of all strings of array. If characters do not match, or length of string is the same as `i` it returns substring result.

I think the best way to understand is debug this example.

Answer (score 0):

If the char in the second string is different than the char in the first one, then it is correct to return, since it means that the common prefix ends there. Checking the third and following strings is not necessary.

Basically it returns as soon as it finds a mismatch char.

Comment: sorry i am still confused...if strs:["fliower","flight","fl"] why does it return fl not fli ?if the third and follwing strings arenot necessary?

Comment: @beautifuldog If the chars are equal then it does check the other strings. It checks the first char with all the first chars of the other strings, then the second char with all the second chars of the other strings, and so on, until it finds a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If we first sort them then it would be very easy we have to only go and compare the first and the last element in the vector present there so, 
the code would be like,This is C++ code for the implementation.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& str) {
        int n = str.size();
        if(n==0) return "";

        string ans  = "";
        sort(begin(str), end(str));
        string a = str[0];
        string b = str[n-1];

        for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
            if(a[i]==b[i]){
                ans = ans + a[i];
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }

        return ans;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
public string LongestCommonPrefix(string[] strs) {


    if(strs.Length == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;

    }

    var prefix = strs[0];
    for(int i=1; i<strs.Length; i++) //always start from 1.index
    {
        while(!strs[i].StartsWith(prefix)) 
        {
            prefix = prefix.Substring(0, prefix.Length-1);

        }

    }
    return prefix;

    
}
}
```

Comment: for C# with love